# wso2 api manager revoke tokens for specific user or application

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, access-token, wso2-api-manager

In wso2 api manager there is Token API that can be used to revoke specific tokens by clients. This is for applications to handle token revocations during logout etc.

But how to revoke all tokens for specific user when I do not want to let user use API anymore? For example when I removed user account from my service.

Is there ani API that can be called from third party application to api manager with information that the user is removed and therefore api manager should invalidate user’s tokens.

Answer (score 0):

In WSO2 API manager, the access token is generated for an Application. When a user is going to use an API, he/she first needs to Subscribe to that API by create an application for that particular API.

So, if you need to revoke a particular token, you should do it for the application. The Token API of the WSO2 API Manager provides a method to revoke the token.

```
curl -k -v -d "token=<ACCESS_TOKEN_TO_BE_REVOKED>" -H "Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded (clientId:clientSecret of the application)>" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:8243/revoke
```

AFAIK, there is ***no straight forward option*** to remove the keys for particular user, as users are subscribed to apis via Applications.

However you could do it by deleting the database entry for that particular user in  `IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN`  table, where all the access token information are stored.

For more information for the Token api, please refer the following documentation.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Token+API

Comment: I found the following and I am currently trying to figure out if it can be used for that purpose: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/WSO2+Admin+Services

Comment: Take a look at APIKeyMgtSubscriberService Admin service and the revokeAccessTokenBySubscriber method.

Answer (score 0):

On a related note: If you want to block a user from accessing APIs, you can use blacklisting feature.

See https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Managing+Throttling#ManagingThrottling-Blacklistingrequests